# Adding Reference Without Using add_static_view

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm building an application in Pyramid and utilizing Jinja2 templates and traversal routing. In order to wire my view-callables with the templates I am using, I want to be able to reference my templates using the `webapp:templates` prefix. As an example:

```
@view_config(name='about-us', renderer='webapp:templates/pages/about-us.html', context=Root)
def static_pages(context, request):
    ... //more code
```

This decouples where the templates live from whats using them. In order to make the above functional, though, I had to put this inside the `__init__.py` in my webapp root folder:

```
config.add_static_view(name='templates', path='webapp:templates', cache_max_age=3600)
```

The `add_static_view()` causes the `webapp/templates` folder to be referenced as `webapp:template` in other configurations. However, it also makes it viewable from a url such as `http://0.0.0.0:6543/templates/<some template file>`. Is there a way to achieve the former goal without allowing the latter visibility as a static page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add_static_view()` *is not supposed* to cause the `webapp/templates` folder to be referenced as `webapp:template` in other configurations, if it does that it's just due to a weird side-effect.

The `package:path` syntax works because Pyramid uses pkg_resources API to resolve the paths. Here are some [details](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/assets.html#understanding-asset-specifications).

This means that, in your example, `webapp` should be a python package located somewhere your app can find it.

Comment: Interesting! So, the `templates` directory just needs to be marked as a package. Many things make more sense to me now!